# How do you create a transactional stream in C++?

Tags: c++, transactions, stream, transactional

I need to create "transactional stream" in C++. What I mean by "transactional stream" is a stream that will rewind if there is an error at some point in the processing. For example,
if a stream's consumer somehow fails to process the stream's data, I want the stream to be reverted to its state before producing that data.

Perhaps a lazy stream would achieve this? Is this a common situation with a common solution or am I bound to writing my own custom implementation for my specific problem?

Comment: That would depend on the stream's underlying implementation (filesystem, network/protocol, etc.). If that supports transactions, and with the semantics you require, you could directly use it. If you want to abstract from that, you'd have to roll your own. Which is non-trivial, if done correctly. For example, don't forget that "transactions" generally not only require a reliable ROLLBACK but also a reliable COMMIT (which is harder to achieve with lazy/memory-backed methods).

Comment: @Christian.K, Good points. I realize it is non-trivial. To be done in an abstract way, I suspect it would be necessary to use something like transactional memory, but provide interfaces for other underlying implementations as you mentioned. I was hoping someone had done that work already (maybe Boost?)! ;)

Comment: Sounds like an application for design patterns. Look at Memento...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first thing that comes to mind is to combine a range interface (for laziness and composability) with a transactional interface (for backtracking):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>

struct transaction_failure {};

class transactional_istream_range {

  std::istream& stream;
  std::stack<std::streampos> states;

public:

  transactional_istream_range(std::istream& stream)
    : stream(stream) {}

  // Transaction interface.

  template<class R, class T>
  R transaction(R(*body)(T&)) {
    try {
      begin();
      R result = body(*this);
      commit();
      return result;
    } catch (const transaction_failure&) {
      rollback();
    }
    return R();
  }

  void begin() {
    states.push(stream.tellg());
  }

  void commit() {
    states.pop();
  }

  void rollback() {
    stream.seekg(states.top());
    states.pop();
  }

  // Range interface.

  bool empty() const {
    return stream.peek() == EOF && stream.eof();
  }

  char front() const {
    return stream.peek();
  }

  void pop_front() const {
    stream.ignore(1);
  }

};
```

You can then easily write template functions operating on transactional ranges:

```
#include <cctype>

template<class R>
std::string parse_integer(R& input) {
  std::string result;
  while (!input.empty()) {
    if (std::isdigit(input.front())) {
      result += input.front();
      input.pop_front();
    } else {
      throw transaction_failure();
    }
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::istringstream stream("1234a");
  typedef transactional_istream_range tir;
  tir input(stream);
  std::string result = input.transaction(parse_integer<tir>);
  std::cout << "Result: " << result;
}
```

This is just a first approximation; you could probably get around having to specify the type of range to the transactional function (i.e., just `parse_integer` rather than `parse_integer<...>`). It’s pretty straightforward to write many kinds of lazy streams and lazy algorithms in range form.

As for extending this, you could parameterise the transaction handling to invoke a user-specified commit or rollback function, or just implement each type of rollback individually. It might also be beneficial to decouple the range interface from the transaction interface using mixins. I can’t think of a good way to do it right now without resorting to virtual functions, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on Windows there's something called Structured Storage which provides a form of transactions. You might have to break your problem up into separate streams.

Here's more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380369(v=vs.85).aspx

Alternatively you could look at using something like [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) or [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) to provide a back-end transactional storage.